# Syntax error on SQL, cant get to work variables on oracle

Tags: sql, triggers

I'm kinda new to mysql and i'm trying to do a relatively simple trigger for an app i'm working on, but i'm afraid I can't seem to find where the error is, as my teacher isn't really helpful... Hope you guys can help me... Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER TR_NUEVOMECA AFTER INSERT ON MECADISTRIBUIDOS FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
VARIABLEBUCLE NUMBER;
MESACTUAL NUMBER;
BEGIN
SET MESACTUAL=(SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW()));
IF (NEW.TIPOASC == 1) THEN
SET VARIABLEBUCLE = 12;
ELSIF (NEW.TIPOASC == 2) THEN
SET VARIABLEBUCLE = 6;
ELSIF(NEW.TIPOASC == 3) THEN
SET VARIABLEBUCLE = 4;
ELSIF(NEW.TIPOASC == 4) THEN
SET VARIABLEBUCLE = 3;
ELSIF(NEW.TIPOASC == 6) THEN
SET VARIABLEBUCLE = 2;
ELSIF(:NEW.TIPOASC == 12) THEN
SET VARIABLEBUCLE = 1;
END IF;
WHILE(VARIABLEBUCLE>0) DO
INSERT INTO MANTENIMIENTOS VALUES(0,:NEW.IDENTIF,NULL,NULL,NULL,MESACTUAL);
SET VARIABLEBUCLE=VARIABLEBUCLE - 1;
SET MESACTUAL=MESACTUAL + NEW.TIPOASC;
IF(MESACTUAL>12) THEN
SET MESACTUAL=MESACTUAL%12;
END IF;
END WHILE;
END;
```

Here's the log photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYQHD.png)
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hello P.Salmon, just added the log to the post

Comment: Those are oracle pl sql errors ,I would edit your question to change any reference to mysql and fix the tags (again)